# Multiple Web Roles inside one Cloud Service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

In my mvc application adding one web role(same project with another web role) in service definition file, but am getting an error like "No Project Associated with(webrole name)".

My query is,

1) Is there any chance to run the one project with two web roles?

2) Presently my application is working one web role with one instance and VMsize="small".but my application running with low performance.

3)Is there any chance to increase the application performance by increasing the number of instance in the role?

Thanks,

PCSSCP.

Answer (score 0):

The error "No Project Associated with ..." means that you have specified the existence of another web role, but there is no project in your solution (ASP.NET webproject, MVC project) that should be deployed as that webrole. Make soure you have two web projects in your solution, when using two web roles.

As an alternative you can deploy to web projects in a single web role.

Increasing the VM size gives your web role more resources (CPU speed, RAM, ...) to perform, which might increase the performance experience for visitors.

Using more instances won't make the application faster, but since all requests are shared amongst the instances, you can serve more users at the same time.